# extract xml attribute value from xpathnavigator

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to get the states code based on state name by the below code:

```
        XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument("D:/Sample.xml");
        XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
        XPathNavigator node =  navigator.SelectSingleNode("//WorldCountry/Country/states/states[@name='Maharastra']");
        string statescode=node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("code").Value

But I am getting error in list line saying that "**XPathNavigator** does not contain a defination of **Attributes**"
```

Comment: I'd bet that it is `states/state` not `states/states` also remember that XML is case sensitive.  You should post a snippet of your XML so that we can verify your code versus the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `GetAttribute` method?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.getattribute.aspx